# Is there an alternative to Random per Island for EEVEE?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, procedural, shader-nodes

I am trying to find a way to have random values assigned to each tile so that I can add a variation to the material later.

[image]

Using the `Geometry Node`'s `Random per Island` output works when using Cycles but it is a Cycles only feature as stated by [the official documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/geometry.html).

Is there a way to have an equivalent result in EEVEE?

Comment: Ideally each tile would be a separate object instance and you would use random per object instead

Comment: Besides Gorgious's answer, this would also be a good workaround. Surprisingly, I didn't even think about that. Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can create a new random attribute per island using Geometry Nodes. Add a Geometry Nodes modifier to your object.

Use a [Mesh Island node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/mesh/mesh_island.html) (specifically, the *Island Index* output) and a [White Noise node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/texture/white_noise.html). Plug the result output to the tree output.

[image]

You can alternatively use a [Random value node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/utilities/random_value.html) and use the mesh island index to stabilize the ID. Then you can play with the seed to get a new random batch of values per island.

[image]

In the modifier tab, expand the *Output Attributes* and type in the name of the attribute. You can choose whatever you want but take care not to overshadow builtins like `UVMap`.

[image]

In the shader editor, use an [Attribute node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/attribute.html) and type in the exact same attribute name (case sensitive).

[image]

[image]

Note that the mesh island indices are dependent on the mesh island with the lowest Z axis vertex. So it may not be consistent if you add mesh islands lowest than the lower part of your mesh.

**Troubleshooting**

There are shading artifacts when using the White Noise Texture in perspective mode. It's caused by the White Noise node in the **shader editor** but the Geometry Nodes solution still applies.

[image]

This setup should get rid of the artifacts and give random colors :

[image]

Or use a Math node set to *Snap*. I guess it comes from a floating point precision error.

[image]

Comment: This answer is gorgeous, no pun intended :D. Thank you very much.

Comment: Great answer. Makes me wonder why native random per island is not supported in EEVEE. Probably same old busy with other stuff.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Thank you ! I think I remember from a post it's because the information comes with very little cost in Cycles due to how the whole thing is streamlined when rendering, whereas it would have a computational hit with Eevee. I don't know for sure though and the technicals are beyond me, so don't quote me on that :)

Comment: just great answer +1