# A node to assign a random color to the roof tiles

Tags: node-editor

In order to assign a different color to each roof tile (and each brick) I used this node:
but it ONLY works on separate objects... Therefore (at least for the moment) to be able to visualize the result I was hoping for, I was forced to separate EVERY single tile of the roof.. we are talking about thousands and thousands of objects... (despite weren't instantiated, separating them weighed down the project enormously..!)
I wonder if there is a node that can achieve the result I want, without having to separate the roof tiles..[image]

Comment: In the shader workspace, Geometry -> Random Per Island

Comment: @Allen Simpson I guess this is the right answer, but does it work only for separate meshes of the same object or does it also work for the separate UVs faces of the same mesh?

Comment: random by island I tried last night... but it didn't work... or am I the one who didn't insert it correctly? Could you explain in which position of the node you would have inserted it? (the i tried instead of random item, random for island)

Comment: Random per island only works with Cycles Render engine

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there an alternative to Random per Island for EEVEE?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/258449/is-there-an-alternative-to-random-per-island-for-eevee)

Comment: I don't get result..can you figure out what I'm doing wrong?
https://i.ibb.co/vPvv4h8/123.jpg (i have changed in 1d sorry for wront screenshot)

Comment: You could help us out, here, by telling us how the tiles are instanced.  Maybe share a toy, stripped-down, bit of roof on  https://blend-exchange.com/, with the tiles instanced in the same way as your entire file.

Comment: Hi Robin! thank you so much! i have upload a small model now! https://blend-exchange.com/b/GWD2nsW6

Comment: basically separating all the roof tiles couldn't be a wrong solution...but in fact when i did it, i created THOUSANDS and THOUSANDS of objects that are not needed... check this photo:
https://i.ibb.co/fnzqgDj/Cattura.jpg
consequently I must have done something wrong when I disconnected the tiles...